# Creating an array of a parent class and adding child objects to it

Tags: java, arrays, class, object, parent

I'm new to Java and I'm trying to write a command line program that calculates section properties for various structural beams. The parent class `Beam()` has child classes `Angle()`, `Tube()`, and `Rectangular()`. I want the user to be able to create new beams and add the beams to a parent array like this:

```
Beam[] beams = new Beam[10];
Tube tb = new Tube(width, height, weight);
Angle ag = new Angle(width, height, flangeWidth);
```

Ideally I'd like to do something like this but I can't because the objects are different types.

```
beams.add(tb);
beams.add(ag);
```

How can I work around this to keep track of the child objects? I'd like to print all objects in the array and give the user the choice to select an object and print out calculated values for it.

Comment: If you are using `Arrays`, should you do something like `beams[0] = tb; beams[1] = ag`?

Comment: The class names are throwing me off. Either `Angular`/`Angled`, `Tubular`, `Rectangular`, or `Angle`, `Tube`, `Rectangle` would be more consistent.

Comment: I think you need to keep reading the tutorial

Comment: Good point about the class names; I'll definitely change them to make them more consistent. Thanks for the comment. I'm in a Java 101 class so I am still learning.

Answer (score 2):

Arrays have no `add` method. You must assign content objects into specific element slots.

```java
Beam[] beams = new Beam[10];
beams[0] = new Tube(width, height, weight);
beams[1] = new Angle(width, height, flangeWidth);
```

More conveniently, use a [`List`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html) such as [`ArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ArrayList.html) rather than a mere array.

```java
List< Beam > beams = new ArrayList <> ( 10 ) ;
beams.add( new Tube(width, height, weight) ) ;
beams.add( new Angle(width, height, flangeWidth) ) ;
```

As commented, this is basic Java 101 stuff. You should spend more time studying the basics, such as the [free tutorial online by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/), or the excellent though somewhat outdated book, *Head First Java* by Kathy Sierra, et al.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's better to use a dynamic array for your work. Do not use `Arrays` use `ArrayList` class in collection API.

```
ArrayList< Beam > beams = new ArrayList <>;
beams.add( new Tube(width, height, weight) ) ;
beams.add( new Angle(width, height, flangeWidth) ) ;
```

As you are new to java please go through the collection API it will help you to use proper data structures when you coding.